# Как избежать исключения, используя функцию getline()?

Tags: c++, строки, классы, исключения

Имеется некоторый класс, который представляет собой простой парсер данных из файла в формате **время, цена**. В конструкторе класса используется конструкция `try catch` для поиска исключений `std::ifstream::failbit` и `std::ifstream::badbit`.

Ниже приведен код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Prices {
    private:
        bool is_number(std::string word) {
            for (auto c : word) {
                if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    public:
        std::vector <int> data;

        Prices(std::string file_name, char delimiter) {
            std::ifstream prices_file;
            prices_file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

            try {
                prices_file.open(file_name, std::ifstream::in);

                std::string line;
                while (getline(prices_file, line)) {
                    size_t pos = line.find(delimiter);

                    if (pos != std::string::npos) {
                        std::string price = line.erase(0, pos + 1);

                        if (is_number(price)) {
                            this->data.push_back(stoi(price));
                        }
                    }
                }

                prices_file.close();
            }
            catch (const std::ifstream::failure& e) {
                std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
};
```

Проблема возникает при инстансе класса `Price`, а именно, после считывания всего потока, функция `getline` выдает исключение `std::ifstream::failbit`. Можно ли это как-нибудь избежать? Никак не могу понять, что стоит исправить в коде?

Буду благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Попробуйте привести код к виду [mcve].

Comment: @Abyx надо было написать *"не включайте режим исключений"* для `fstream`.

Comment: @Abyx, если не использовать std::ifstream::failbit, то не получиться отследить исключение в функции std::ifstream::open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию потоки **не** генерируют исключения.
Так что я бы на вашем месте их и вовсе не использовал, а обошелся бы вашим циклом, который просто завершился бы без всяких исключений.

Т.е. по сути изменения - убрать

```
prices_file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
```

да и `try-catch` заодно.